# For Loop Not displaying the lowest but the first in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

Guys, I'm new to Arrays, I'm making a program that takes 2 parallel arrays finds both the lowest and the highest values then based on the value it will take the highest string array value related to the integer arrays and then outputs the related lowest and related highest results on the screen.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<climits>


//Prototypes:

using namespace std;

void getJars(string[], int[], int);
int getTotal(string[], int[], int);
int getLowest(string[], int[], int);


int main() {

    string salsa[] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty" };
    const int NUM = 5;
    int lowest = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int jars[NUM];

    getJars(salsa, jars, NUM);
    total = getTotal(salsa, jars, NUM);
    cout << endl << "Total of Jars Sold This Month: " << total << endl;
    lowest = getLowest(salsa, jars, NUM);
    cout << endl << lowest << endl;


    return 0;
}

void getJars(string salsa[], int jars[], int NUM) {



cout << "Salsa Sales Calculator...\n";
cout << "------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {

        cout << "Please Insert the Jar Amount for Each Salsa: ";
        cout << salsa[i];
        cout << " ";
        cin >> jars[i];

        cout << endl;
    }


    return;
}
int getTotal(string salsa[], int jars[], int NUM) {

    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {

        total += jars[i];
    }

    return total;
}

int getLowest(string salsa[], int jars[], int NUM) {

    int lowest = jars[0];
    string lowSalsa;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        if(lowest > jars[i])
            lowest = jars[i];


    return lowest;
}
```

I'm trying to see why it only gives me the first value of the array not the lowest. Could someone please help.

Comment: Use your debugger, Luke

Comment: I was actually never taught to use the debugger... I don't know how

Comment: Then you need to learn how to use a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: where is the } that closes the for loop?

Comment: _"I was actually never taught to use the debugger"_ -- If you wait to be taught everything you'll always be behind.  This is a basic, required skill and you should study and learn it ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop returns on the first iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(lowest > jars[i])
        lowest = jars[i];


  return lowest;
}
```

Switch the "return" and the "}" and it should work more correctly. I strongly advise using braces with your if statements as well, for clarity.
Nice code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I should learn how to debug, though. If you guys have a video that helped you guys learn I'd really appreciate it. Thanks again:)